# NSXMLParser and error constants

Tags: cocoa

Is there a description of the various errors that NSXMLParser can return? I'm aware of the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001984-SW1) of these codes, but this page doesn't give anything other than a title for the error.

Comment: While I answered below with as much information as I could, I don't think I got at what you were asking. Is there some specific kind of information about an NSXMLParserError that you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `enum` defines all of the `NSXMLParserError`s. If you want (slightly) more detail, you can click on a particular constant in the list.

Comment: That's all the further I was able to go, too.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because it looks like the best possible answer. Thanks,